# Multi field updates in document in java mongodb

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, spring-mongodb

Below is my mongob document structure

```
{
"employee_id":"123",
"employee_name":"ABC",
"elements":[
{

"element_name":"Verification Id",
"element_value":"Test Address",
"element_status":"selected"

},

{

"element_name":"Reportees",
"element_value":["ABC","DEF"],
"element_status":"selected"

}
,

{

"element_name":"Countries",
"element_value":["China","USA"],
"element_status":"selected"

}

]
}
```

My input will be `{"countries":["Russia","Japan"],"Verification Id":"license"}.`

My requirement is to update the only the countries and Verification Id element values for the given employee id. Reportees should remain untouched.

What are the ways to achieve this using java mongodb.

I tried following approaches

1)

```
collection.updateMany(Filters.and(Filters.eq("employee_id", "123"),Filters.eq("elements.element_name", "Verification Id"))
                ,
                Updates.combine(
                    Updates.set("elements.$.element_value", "license"),
                   Updates.set("elements.$.element_status", "changed"),
                ));
and 



collection.updateMany(Filters.and(Filters.eq("employee_id", "123"),Filters.eq("elements.element_name", "Countries")))
                ,
                Updates.combine(
                    Updates.set("elements.$.element_value", ["Russia","Japan"]),
                   Updates.set("elements.$.element_status", "changed"),
                ));
```

The disadvantage here is that I end up making 2 db calls. If more such parameters come as input, then the number of db calls to perform the update increases

2.)

```
List<DBObject> array = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
        BasicDBObject bObj=new BasicDBObject();
        bObj.put("element_name", "Countries");
        bObj.put("element_value", ["Russia","Japan"]);
        bObj.put("element_status", "changed");

        BasicDBObject bObj1=new BasicDBObject();
        bObj1.put("element_name", "Verification Id");
        bObj1.put("element_value", "license");
        bObj1.put("element_status", "changed");

        array.add(bObj);
        array.add(bObj1);


collection.updateMany(Filters.eq("employee_id", "123"),
                Updates.combine(
                    Updates.set("elements", array)
                ));
```

The disadvantage is that it completly over writes the elements array and removes the array element "element_name":"Reportees".

PLease guide me further on this. PLease let me know the best way to update select fields based on different criteria.